# BinaryEncoder on test set causes different feature count than on training set

Tags: machine-learning, python, neural-network

I am using a BinaryEncoder from the category_encoders package. I used it to encode a feature in my training set: 30k samples, 1170 unique categories for the feature in question, that resulted in 12 new features. I am trying to apply the same encoder to the test set (5000 samples, 603 unique categories), that resulted in 11 new features. The problem is that now the fitted model cannot predict on the test set because the dimensions do not match (36 total features vs 35 in the test set).

**Edit:** the test set is a separate file on which I have to do predictions, not part of the training set split by me.

`Input 0 of layer dense is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 36 but received input with shape (None, 35)`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Split train/test stratifies on this Feature. Test data should be transform only with the encoder fit on train data.

Comment: Re: the edit, the second sentence of @10xAI's comment is still the right answer.  (Do we have a canonical answer for this, that we can mark this as duplicate?)

Comment: That was not an option as I had to stratify my dataset on the target feature in order to keep class balance. I ended up using FeatureHasher instead of BinaryEncoder, as it  allows for determination of the number of features: `FeatureHasher(n_features=n)`, while BinaryEncoder returns a number of new features based on the number of unique categories in the original feature.